# Converting a form input values to JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've been having trouble finding information to help me learn and understand the concepts of JavaScript and JSON.

I've created an HTML document that has input for 'to', 'cc', 'subj' and a text area 'compose'.

After the user fills in the input boxes and text, the user clicks the "send" button and the information is logged in the console.

The onclick function I'm using now is:

```
function send() {
    var toEmail = $("#to").val();
    var ccEmail = $("#cc").val();
    var subject = $("#subj").val();
    var content = $("#compose").val();

    console.log(toEmail);
    console.log(ccEmail);
    console.log(subject);
    console.log(content);
}
```

When I click "send" now, the information is logged like:

[image: Current:]

I want the console to show:

```
   {"to":"test_email@hotmail.com}

   {"cc":"ccEmail@hotmail.com}

   {"subj":"Testing"}

   {"compose":"Send to console"}
```

I know this is likely very basic. However, I am struggling to grasp JSON when working with user input.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also explain why you want this? Do you want to use these objects somehow? Do you need them combined in one object? Understanding the purpose will help to get good answers. I simple answer could be: do `console.log({toEmail});` with the additional braces. But it feels useless without knowing what this is about.

Comment: BTW: the title of your question is misleading: you don't want to convert a function to JSON, you (seem to) want a function to convert input to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap the output in an object. Then you can use **JSON.stringify** to change the object into a JSON (string).

```
function send() {
    var toEmail = $("#to").val();
    var ccEmail = $("#cc").val();
    var subject = $("#subj").val();
    var content = $("#compose").val();

    var result = {
        to: toEmail,
        cc: ccEmail,
        subj: subject,
        compose: content
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));   /*{"to":"test_email@hotmail.com",
                                              "cc":"ccEmail@hotmail.com",
                                              "subj":"Testing",
                                              "compose":"Send to console"} */
    return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

For all individual strings you may do:

```
function send() {
    var toEmail = $("#to").val();
    var ccEmail = $("#cc").val();
    var subject = $("#subj").val();
    var content = $("#compose").val();

    console.log(JSON.stringify({to: toEmail});
    console.log(JSON.stringify({cc: ccEmail});
    console.log(JSON.stringify({subj: subject});
    console.log(JSON.stringify({compose: content});
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is something similar to what I'm looking for. But I want all 4 vars in individuals JSON strings.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks. It's new to me so working with $, #, and stringify is all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

with `Array.prototype.reducer`,

```js
function send() {
    const payload = ['to', 'cc', 'subj', 'compose'].reduce((acc, el) => {
        acc[el] = $(`#${el}`).val();

        return acc;
    }, {});

    console.log(payload);
}
```